# Как поменять местами две половины массива натуральных чисел, сохраняя их порядок

Tags: массивы, java

Как поменять местами две половины массива натуральных чисел, сохраняя их порядок

Comment: Домашнее задание?

На C#:

    arr.Skip(arr.Length/2).Concat(arr.Take(arr.Length/2)).ToArray()

Comment: Не дз. Просто балуюсь для самопросвещения))

Comment: вы самопросвещаетесь, прося решить за вас задачу? Гораздо лучше было бы решить самому. Тем более такую несложную

Answer (score 1):

Если массив имеет четное число элементов, то с ним все понятно, если нечетное, то нужно подумать, как поступить с центральным элементом. В примере ниже - он остается на своем месте.

```
int hlen = arr.length /2;
int cpos = hlen + arr.length % 2;
for (int i = 0; i < hlen; i++) {
  int t = arr[i];
  arr[i] = arr[cpos + i];
  arr[cpos + i] = t;
}
```

Но если нужно быстрее - то копировать нужно в новый массив, используя arraycopy.

Comment: спс. забыл написать что в jave.

Comment: а разве это  не на java?

Comment: и к стати с данным кодом он просто обрезает первую половине массива.

Comment: код проверил, он работает как задумано. Может точнее напишете, как оно у Вас "обрезает" и поправите ошибки?

Comment: @KoVadim, а что еще можно придумать с центральным элементом? Так что, только как у Вас.

А как думаете, начиная с какого размера массива arraycopy ускорит программу? Понятно, что для маленьких только замедлит.

Comment: могу сказать, что на андроиде (где также java), замена цикла на arraycopy ускоряет до 9 раз. Реальное ускорение начнется с 4-8 элементов. arraycopy может быть jit'ом заменен на прямое копирование памяти.

Comment: @avp, почему замедлит? откуда такая инфа, я как помню, он в любом случае должен работать быстрее...

Comment: видимо @avp имеет ввиду накладные расходы на вызов метода.

Comment: Конечно, выделение памяти под промежуточный массив + вызов arraycopy.

В реализации от Oracle насколько помню идет несколько вызовов Java, а последний native (его в сорсах Java, которые я смотрел уже не было).

Comment: @avp решение @KoVadim для центрального элемента нарушает условия задачи, поскольку для нечётной длины мы имеем разбиение массива на три части: до центра, центр и после центра.

Видимо, для нечётной длины решения нет, поскольку или одна половина больше другой, или частей -- три.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder("1111112222222");
StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
res.append(strb.substring(strb.length()/2,strb.length()).append(strb.substring(0,strb.length()/2);
```

Comment: У ТС вроде массив чисел, а не символов.

Comment: согласен, но тут всего 3 строчки кода + 2 строчки что бы конвертнуть туда-сюда, не проблема